# (OO Design) Decorator + State Patterns but the states and decorators are user-defined

Tags: java, decorator, state-pattern

Alright, so I’m facing a design problem for software I’m writing. Basically, I need a combination of decorator and state patterns… Except the users can define the specific decorators and their states. To my surprise, I couldn’t find anything that already exists that serves my needs.

Brief explanation: it’s a linguistics application that’s supposed to be used for any kind of language. Languages are complicated, so I need a system that leaves enough flexibility to the user to add the components he needs. My problem arises with those components, which I call “Modifiers”.

Words in a spoken language are basically a sequence of Phonemes (either Vowel or Consonant).

Phonemes have Features (inherent properties; the ability to filter Phonemes based based on shared Features is essential), but they also have Modifiers.

A modifier is basically a toggle or a dial for specific features that can be turned on or off (e.g. a vowel can be long or short), or that can have different states (e.g. vowel tones like in Chinese; Chinese has 5 different tones, a vowel has 1 of these at any given time). The presence of a modifier is essential to the phoneme, but its exact state does not turn it into a different phoneme altogether. It’s essential that the user can define their own STATES. I could provide an enum with an array of common states (DISABLED, ENABLED, LONG, SHORT, HEAVY, LIGHT, FALLING_TONE,…) but that leaves the application vulnerable to inappropriate states being applied to Modifiers that shouldn’t have a certain state (e.g. a consonant can’t have a falling tone).

For a given language, the user will have to define its phonemes (as well as its features and modifiers) in advance. The problem is the Modifier States. Since they aren’t pre-defined I can’t use a Decorator + State pattern as I otherwise would. There’s no enum or concrete classes, only user-created objects.

My solution is to create a WordPhoneme-class that has a Map. A Word then has a List. Obviously, I’ll provide the necessary methods to check if a certain ModifierState is allowed for a certain Modifier etc. In this way, for a specific phoneme in a specific word can get a specific state AND I avoid making 5000 copies of the same handful of phonemes just to be able to change their modifier states.

But is this the most optimal solution?

My code (not everything is implemented yet, need to get the design on point first):

```
public class Word {
    private List<WordPhoneme> phonemeSequence;
    public Word(List<Phoneme> phonemeSequence) {
        // turn List<Phoneme> into a List<WordPhoneme>, by giving each Modifier its default state.
    }
}

public class WordPhoneme {
    private Word word;
    private Phoneme phoneme;
    private Map<Modifier, ModifierState> modifierStates;
    public WordPhoneme (Word word, Phoneme phoneme) {
        this.word = word;
        this.phoneme = phoneme;
        // Map<Modifier, ModifierState> get created, each Modifier gets its default state
    }
    public Word getWord() { /* */ };
    public Phoneme getPhoneme() { /* */ };
    public List<Modifier> getModifiers;
    public ModifierState getModifierState(Modifier modifier) { /* */ }
    public void changeModifierState(Modifier modifier, ModifierState state) { /* throws error if not a legal state */ }
}

public abstract class Phoneme {    
    private final String notation;
    private final List<Feature> secondaryFeatures; // voice, aspiration, palatalization, semivowel, roundedness, nasalization, vowel tones,…
    private Phoneme() { /* not allowed */ }
    public Phoneme(String notation){
        this.notation = notation;
        this.secondaryFeatures = null;
    }
    public Phoneme(String notation, List<Feature> secondaryFeatures){
        this(notation);
        this.secondaryFeatures = secondaryFeatures
    }
    public List<Feature> getSecondaryFeatures() { /* */ }
    public List<Modifier> getModifiers() { /* */}
    public boolean hasFeature(Feature feature) { /* */ }
    public boolean hasModifier(Modifier modifier) { /* */ }
    public ModifierState getModifierState(Modifier modifier) { /* */ }
    public List<ModifierState> getPossibleModifierStates(Modifier modifier) { /* */}
    public void changeModifierState(Modifier modifier, ModifierState state) { /* */ }
}

public class Consonant extends Phoneme {
    private final Feature placeOfArticulation;
    private final Feature mannerOfArticulation;
    private Consonant() { /* not allowed */ }
    public Consonant(String notation, Feature poa, Feature moa) {
        super(notation);
        placeOfArticulation = poa;
        mannerOfArticulation = moa;
    }
    public Consonant(String notation, Feature poa, Feature moa, List<Feature> secondaryFeatures) {
        super(notation, secondaryFeatures);
        placeOfArticulation = poa;
        mannerOfArticulation = moa;
    }
    public Feature getPlaceOfArticulation() { /* */ }
    public Feature getMannerOfArticulation() { /* */ }
}

public class Vowel extends Phoneme {
    private final Feature height;
    private final Feature backness;
    private Vowel() { /* not allowed */ }
    public Vowel(String notation, Feature height, Feature backness) {
        super(notation);
        this.height = height;
        this.backness = backness;
    }
    public Consonant(String notation, Feature height, Feature backness, List<Feature> secondaryFeatures) {
        super(notation, secondaryFeatures);
        this.height = height;
        this.backness = backness;
    }
    public Feature getHeight() { /* */}
    public Feature getBackness() { /* */ }
}

// A feature is inherent to the phoneme; changing a feature changes the phoneme.
public class Feature {
    private final String name;
}

// A modifier slightly alters the phoneme whilst still retaining the phoneme’s defining features.
// A modifier can have a user-defined list of possible states. This allows for more flexibility than
// having a simple enabled/disabled toggle, e.g. the use of multiple tones, multiple degrees of vowel
// length e.g.
public class Modifier {
    private final String name;
    private final ModifierState defaultState;
    private final List<ModifierState> possibleStates;
    private Modifier() { /* not allowed */ }
    public Modifier(String name, ModifierState defaultState, List<ModifierState> possibleStates) {
        // check if the defaultState is a member of possibleStates
    }
    public List<ModifierStates> getPossibleModifierStates() { /* */ }
}

public class ModifierState {
    private final String name;
}
```

You might ask: but why modifiers? Isn’t it easier to make each Modifier be a specific Feature, and then increase the amount of phonemes, to differentiate the different Features?

No, because: 
1) they aren’t separate phonemes and I’d have to implement an extra class or something something to keep related phonemes together, and 
2) advanced features include conjugation/declension and language evolution… often a phoneme’s modifier gets changed to a different state when the word gets inflected… it would be an implementation nightmare to get this right if the user has to make separate phonemes out of them.

Comment: I don't think your "States" have something to do with the actual [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). Your states are just some values, aren't they?

Comment: Are Modifiers defined specific to a Phoneme?

Comment: @lexicore: they are a set of user-defined values, yes, though every specific Modifier "type" will have the exact same set of "ModifierStates". For example: in Chinese, a vowel has a Modifier for "vowel tone" which gives a vowel any of 5 "ModifierStates": HIGH, RISING, LOW, FALLING, NEUTRAL. Another language might also have vowel tone, but only 3 possible and completely different "ModifierStates".

Comment: @nitnamby: no, a Modifier can be used in multiple Phonemes. E.g. a language might have 5 vowels and 3 of them share the Modifier "vowel length" which has the states "LONG" and "SHORT" (or "ENABLED" and "DISABLED" if the user prefers).